# jquery bind function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is for chat application using jQuery. The `fetchMsg` method works just fine. The problem is in entry class textarea , for some reason `bind` function doesn't work . It doesn't respond for any key event. I've tried `live` function and `on` function. Is the problem is in javascript or I should change textarea tag to input type text tag?

```
// delcare new js global object

var chat = {}

chat.entry = $('.chat .entry');

// binding keydown event handler
// THIS PART DOESNT WORK 
chat.entry.bind('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey === false) {
    chat.throwMsg($(this).val());
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});

// fetch msgs method
chat.fetchMsg = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'engine/chat.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      method: 'fetch'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.chat .msgs').html(data);
    }
  });
}
chat.throwMsg = function(msg) {
  if ($.trim(msg).length != 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'engine/chat.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        method: 'throw',
        msg: msg
      },
      success: function(data) {
        chat.fetchMsg();
        chat.entry.val('');
      }
    });
  }
}

chat.interval = setInterval(chat.fetchMsg, 2000);
```

Comment: where is the html markup

Comment: Is your code in the `document.ready()` handler?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post the relevant HTML portion as well

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does the event handler trigger?

Comment: God, your keyboard has the key for `.`, or any other sentence delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(funciton(){
$(document).on('keydown', '.chat .entry', function (evt) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey === false)
    {
        chat.throwMsg($(this).val());
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

});